# VSTO Outlook AddIn: Cannot use Explorer Close event

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin

some time ago I programmed an Outlook AddIn using NetOffice which worked very well. Now with the new Visual Studio Community 2017 I can program Office AddIns without the help of NetOffice. So I want to change my code, but I ran into a problem: I cannot subcsribe to the `Explorer.Close` event:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
namespace OLTest2
{
    public class ExplorerHandle
    {
        private Outlook.Explorer OutlookExplorer;
        public void InitExplorer(Outlook.Explorer expl)
        {
            OutlookExplorer = expl;
            // The next two lines compile:
            OutlookExplorer.BeforeItemPaste += BeforeItemPasteEvent;
            OutlookExplorer.SelectionChange += SelectionChangeEvent;

            // ***Next line does not compile***:
            OutlookExplorer.Close += CloseEvent; // "Cannot assign to 'Close' because it is a 'method group'"
            
            // This is the old NetOffice code which worked fine:
            /* 
            OutlookExplorer.BeforeItemPasteEvent += BeforeItemPasteEvent;
            OutlookExplorer.SelectionChangeEvent += SelectionChangeEvent;
            OutlookExplorer.CloseEvent += CloseEvent; 
            */ 
        }
    }
}
```

IntelliSense does not show me the existence of a `Close` event for an `Outlook.Explorer` object. But Microsoft tells me that such an event should exist:

[Explorer events on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.explorer?view=outlook-pia#events_)

However, Visual Studio tells me that there's only a `Close()` method.

I'm missing something, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast OutlookExplorer variable above to `ExplorerEvents` interface.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Dmitry, who pointed me in the right direction. The solution for the `Close` event is:
`((Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_Event)OutlookExplorer).Close += CloseEvent;`

And in case somebody has a similar problem with `OutlookInspector`:
A cast is necessary for e.g. the `Activate` event:
`((Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event)OutlookInspector).Activate += ActivateEvent;`

But I'm curious: Why do I have to cast to subscribe for `Close`, but not for `BeforeItemPaste`?
According to the link I posted in my original question both events are "Inherited from ExplorerEvents_10_Event".

Comment: Because for BeforeItemPaste there is no property or method with the same name. Close  and Activate are ambiguous.